# How to assign a user to an employee in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am a beginner in django and trying to create a web application for my task.
I am trying to assign a user to every to employee.
The idea is that user(in my class Employee) brings a list of user options that have not yet been assigned to the new employee to be registered.

My model:

```
class Employee():

  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  job = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return'{}'.format(self.name,self.job,self.user)
```

My form:

```
  class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
 
    user= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(id=Employee.user))
    
  class Meta:
     model = Employee
    
     fields = [
        'name',
        'job',
        'user'
     ]
```

My view:

```
def register_employee(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
     return redirect('list_employee')
  else:
     form = EmployeeForm()
  return render(request, 'employee/employee_form.html',{'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your code to be modified as,

```
  class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
 
    user= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(employee=None))
```

Please try the above.